# SharePoint OPTIONS preflight request

Tags: sharepoint, servicestack, cors, sharepoint-2013

I have a Service Stack service hosted within a SharePoint 2013 site. When attempting to make a cross domain request to one of the services, a preflight `OPTIONS` request is made, as expected.

The problem is that the response always comes back as `401 Unauthorized`, due to the fact that authentication info is not sent across with the request. I have tried putting some request filters via servicestack to try and bypass the authentication, but these filters are not firing - it seems like something prior to service stack is sending the response.

Is there any way of specifying that `OPTIONS` requests to the sharepoint site do not need to be authenticated? If not, does anyone have a workaround for this scenario?

I tried 'fooling' the browser in to not sending a preflight request by changing the data type from `application/json` to `text/plain` in my ajax request, but then the data I send is not being deserialised in to the correct RequestDTO for the service calls on the server side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up having to write our own HTTP module in order to support the options request. We basically add a key specifying which domains to allow the CORS requests from (can support more than one) and then have this HTTP module registered:

```
    public class ECSPreFlightModule : IHttpModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this module in the Web.config file of your
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>


        public void Dispose()
        {
            //clean-up code here.
        }

        private const string OptionsHeader = "OPTIONS";
        private const string OriginHeader = "ORIGIN";
        private const string AccessAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        private string AllowedOriginUrlsArray
        {
            get
            {
                return GetWebConfigValue("CORSAllowedOriginUrls");
            }
        }


        private string GetWebConfigValue(string key)
        {
            var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            object o = configuration.GetSection("system.web/httpModules");
            var section = o as HttpModulesSection;
            return section.CurrentConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value; 
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var splitUrls = AllowedOriginUrlsArray.Split('|');
                var response = context.Response;
                var originHeader = context.Request.Headers.Get(OriginHeader);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originHeader) && splitUrls.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var url in splitUrls)
                    {
                        var urlLower = url.ToLower();
                        var originHeaderLower = originHeader.ToLower();
                        // if the method being requested is an OPTIONS request and the url is the url specified in the web.config then return an OK response.
                        if (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToLowerInvariant() == OptionsHeader.ToLowerInvariant() &&
                              (urlLower == originHeaderLower))
                        {
                            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                        }
                        // If the originating header url is equal to the url specified in the web.config then grant the access control
                        if (originHeaderLower == urlLower)
                        {
                            response.AddHeader(AccessAllowOrigin, originHeader);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

    }
}
```

The above module was wrapped in a sharepoint feature that, when activated, made the appropriate changes to the web.config, namely registering the module and adding the following keys:

```
 <add name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' value='true' />
 <add name='Access-Control-Allow-Headers' value='Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, X-RequestDigest' />
 <add name='Access-Control-Allow-Methods' value='GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT, DELETE' />
```